# Visual Studio keeps trying to look for old NuGet package versions when checking in code to DevOps

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

VS Pro 2019 v16.11.11.

Every time I check in code in my DevOps project repos (VSTS), Visual Studio throws this error referring to *some* old versions of *some* NuGet packages in the /packages folder that I don't reference anymore and have been upgraded to new versions.

I've tried reinstalling the old version and then re-upgrading and uninstalling, and it still keeps throwing these errors. I've tried deleting the packages folder, cleaning the solution, etc.

The only way I've found to get past this is to create a dummy project and add references to these old NuGet package versions, just so I won't get the error and can check in code. In fact on some of these NuGet packages, it throws this error for *multiple* versions, and I have to keep adding dummy projects to hold references to additional versions.

Please help; I'm not sure what else to try. I cannot find any references to these old versions in any of the packages.config, project files, or solution file, so I'm not even sure where they are coming from.

[image]

Comment: You should be ignoring the `packages` folder, see [Omitting packages with Team Foundation Version Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control#omitting-packages-with-team-foundation-version-control) Try pulling down all the missing changes so you can then delete the `packages` folder from being controlled and then ignore it.

Comment: @DaveAnderson, thank you, yes that's it. Forgot to add these to ignore.